# Keyup Blur functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does

```
$(document).on("keyup blur", "#my_selector", function() {
    //DO SOMETHING
});
```

seems to work, however

```
$("#my_selector").on("keyup blur", function() {
    //DO SOMETHING
});
```

Doesn't? I put them both in my ready functions, and while the above one works, the lower one doesn't. This is in context of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868378/passing-a-jquery-object-in-event-delegation).

Comment: check #my_selector, maybe it is not well written?

Comment: When you say your `ready` function, what object did you attach that to? Where's that code?

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mDaCr/

Comment: both your examples have syntax errors. `});` too many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('selector').on('event')` works like $.bind.
`$(document).on('event', 'selector')` works like $.live.

In other words, `$('selector').on` attaches an event handler *to a currently existing node*.

If `$('#my_selector')` is empty at the time of the event handler's creation, the event handler will not be attached to it.

On the other hand `$(document)` is always available, and you can always attach event handlers to it.
`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() { ... })` attaches an event handler to document and filters it by 'selector'. So this works just like `$().live()` in previous versions of jQuery, and you should use event binding in this way.

Comment: That explains. My thing is getting generated dynamically only.

Answer (score 3):

If the `#my_selector` item is added dynamically (e.g. after an Ajax call finishes) then you may be attaching the `direct` event handler before the element exists in the DOM. In this case the event handler would be attached to nothing. The first one attaches a `delegated` event handler so it does not matter when the element appears in the DOM, the event handler would be executed.